# Функции как аргументы другой функции

Tags: python, python-3.x, функции

Есть задание:

> Напишите функцию composition(f, g), которая принимает на вход две
>   функции: f и g, и возвращает их композицию h(x) = f(g(x)). Определите
>   функцию композиции, предполагая, что аргументы у функции g могут быть
>   какие угодно, и любое возвращаемое функцией g значение будет
>   корректным аргументом для функции f.

Как передать результат выполнения `g` в `f`, если `f` - сам аргумент?

Не доходит до меня эта абстракция.

PS в задании рекомендуют использовать замыкания.

Comment: Не совсем понимаю, что вы имеете ввиду под словом композиция

Comment: В задании: назовём композицией  двух заданных функций, f и g, функцию h, для которой:
h(x) = f(g(x))h(x)=f(g(x))

Comment: В python все сущности равноправны и являются объектами. Функции не исключение. Можете передавать их в качестве аргументов, можете возвращать. Для решения вам нужно определить новую функцию внутри функции композиции (полноценную именованную или лямбду) и вернуть ее.

Comment: @Gari [Композиция функций](https://ru.wikipedia.org/wiki/%D0%9A%D0%BE%D0%BC%D0%BF%D0%BE%D0%B7%D0%B8%D1%86%D0%B8%D1%8F_%D1%84%D1%83%D0%BD%D0%BA%D1%86%D0%B8%D0%B9)

Comment: Тяжело мне дается это понимание.
К примеру, это не работает.
    def composition(f, g):
        def inner (f,g):
            return f(g)
        return inner (f,g)

Comment: @MikhailBelousov `inner` должна быть функцией от `x` а не от `f, g` и в конце `return inner` а не `return inner(f, g)`. вам нужно вернуть функцию, а не результат ее применения.

Answer (score 5):

Пример:

```
def g(*args):
    return sum(*args)

def f(x):
    return x**2

def composition(f, g):
    def func(*args):
        return f(g(*args))
    return func
```

---

Пример использования:

```
In [16]: composition(f, g)([1, 2, 3])
Out[16]: 36
```

---

Используем ту же функцию-композицию с другими функциями:

```
In [20]: def f2(s):
    ...:     return s[::-1]
    ...:
    ...: def g2(s):
    ...:     return ''.join(s[::2])
    ...:

In [21]: composition(f2, g2)("0123456789")
Out[21]: '86420'
```

Comment: Да, такой вариант очевиден, но система проверки его не пропускает  и рекомендует использовать замыкания.

Comment: @MikhailBelousov, `"рекомендует использовать замыкания"` - о таких вещах лучше сообщать в теле вопроса ;)

Comment: Вот теперь дошло, что к чему. Взял на вооружение.

Comment: @MaxU В Haskell композиция определена как `(.) f g = \x -> f (g x)` иначе это можно записать так `(f . g) x = f (g x)`. Не то, чтобы эта реализация была эталоном, но вполне соответствует определению.

Comment: @MikhailBelousov, [Что делать с ответами на вопрос?](https://ru.stackoverflow.com/help/someone-answers)